# JS - Split string into substrings by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string that starts by `7878` and ends by `0d0a` or `0D0A` such as:

```
var string = "78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a";
var string2 = "78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a78780d0103588990504943870016efe20d0a";
var string 3 = "78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a78780d0103588990504943870016efe20d0a78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a"
```

How can I split it by regex so it becomes an array like:

```
['78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a']
['78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a','78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a']
['78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a','78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a','78780d0101234567890123450016efe20d0a']
```

Comment: I wouldn't use regex, I would use length; it looks like they are always the same length?

Comment: Im sorry, bad example. They are not always the same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string with a positive lookahead `(?=7878)`. The regex isn't consuming any characters, so `7878` will be part of the string.

```
var rgx = /(?=7878)/;
console.log(string1.split(rgx));
console.log(string2.split(rgx));
console.log(string3.split(rgx));
```

Another option is to split on `'7878'` and then take all the elements except first and add `'7878'` to each of them. For example:

```
var arr = string3.split('7878').slice(1).map(function(str){
    return '7878' + str;
});
```

> That works BUT it also matches strings that do NOT end on `0d0a`. How
>   can I only matches those ending on `0d0a` OR `0D0A`?

Well, then you can use `String.match` with a plain regex.

```
console.log(string3.match(/7878.*?0d0a/ig));
```

Comment: That works BUT it also matches strings that do NOT end on `0d0a`. How can I only matches those ending on `0d0a` OR `0D0A`?

Comment: Works! Supposing all characters in the string are hex, can I use this regex as well? `/7878[a-f0-9]+?0d0a/ig`